# XPages Dojo DataGrid and REST Service do not save editable columns changes

Tags: datagrid, xpages

We have a REST Service and Dojo DataGrid that does not save the changes to editable columns on the initial load -- meaning the XPage loads and changes are made.  The only way the changes are saved is after the close() or revert() method for the REST service is called, then the save() method is called.  The REST Service is pointing to another database on the same server, and uses the keys property:

```
<xe:restService id="rsVictims" pathInfo="rsVictimsData">
<xe:this.service>
    <xe:viewItemFileService defaultColumns="true"
        viewName="InvoiceGridVictims" contentType="application/json"
        databaseName="voca\vocadatastore.nsf" keys="k28ts71zrjsw">
    </xe:viewItemFileService>
</xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
```

Here is the DataGrid:

```
<xe:djxDataGrid id="djxDataGrid1" storeComponentId="rsVictims"
    autoHeight="90">
    <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn1"
        label="Target" width="35px" field="victimTarget">
    </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
    <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn2"
        label="Oct" width="35px" field="month_10" editable="true">
    </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
</xe:djxDataGrid>
```

It flows like this:

Open the XPage with the REST service and DataGrid

Make changes to the editable columns
Click the Save button which calls this code (code is copied from [Brad Balassaitis' demo](http://xcellerant.net/2013/09/05/dojo-data-grids-sample-database-on-openntf/), 06 Custom Control):

```
 <xp:button value="Save Changes" id="victimsSaveButton">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[// Save the changes...
editedRows = [-1];
var args = {onError: function() {alert('error!');}};
rsVictims.save(args);

//Refresh the grid
rsVictims.close();
dijit.byId('#{id:djxDataGrid1}')._refresh();]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
```

DataGrid is closed, refreshed, but changes are NOT saved

Make changes again and click the Save button
DataGrid is closed, refreshed, and changes are now saved

What I have noticed is that the DataGrid is loaded twice when the XPage is opened -- I see this is Firebug in the Net tab.  On the first GET, it retrieves the grid correctly -- the Response is correct, the JSON is formatted correctly, and the start=0 with a count=25.

On the second GET, it seems to lose the grid -- the Response is empty, the JSON items is empty, and the start=25 with the count=25.  I have tried setting the start property in the REST Service to 0, but that does not do anything.  I have tried setting the count property to 500 as well, but that does not fix it either.

The interesting fact about this is, when the view is moved inside the current database -- so the databaseName property on the REST Service is not used -- the Save button works perfectly.  Also, there is only one GET when loading the DataGrid, not two GETs when pointing to a view in another database on the same server.  I know there are some issues when looking to another server, but these databases are on the same server.

I know I have posted about [this topic before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055940/xpages-dojo-grid-editable-cell-does-not-save-value-when-rest-service-save-meth), but I did not get an answer that worked.  I am hoping this sheds some more light on what I may be missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dan, if this question is the exact same as the other, then update the original question - as this question will be closed as a duplicate. Once you have some more reputation points, you can then add a bounty to the original question to get more attention on answering the question

Comment: I didn't see your comment, let me know if you want me to move my answer to the other question.

Comment: @Per - I have moved this question to the other one as requested.

Comment: I have moved my answer as well.  This question can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Dan,

I have nearly an identical situation in my current project.  I have mine working perfect so I think I can help.   I assume that you already took Per Lausten's suggestion in your previous SO.  You wouldn't be able to save at all if you didn't.

The difference between your code and mine is that I am using a xe:viewJSONService instead of a  xe:viewFileItemService.  The extention library book says that you have to use the viewFileItem  if you want it updatable, but this is NOT true.

I had nothing but trouble with the viewItemFileService, see this blog post for the issues I had (http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/07/going-with-extjs-grid-and-giving-up-on.html)  I nearly gave up entirely on the dojo grid, but came back to it because it works on mobile.

Using the viewJSONService just works.  Instead of a keys property, use the category filter.  For you category have code similar to this:

```
var category:String = lineItemBean.getThisUNID();
if(category == null){
    return "show nothing"
} else {
    return lineItemBean.getThisUNID();
}
//prevents all records from being returned
```

You need to be careful, because if the category is null, all records are returned, which could be a big problem or security hole.  In my example, I pull from a bean, but you could put a document reference there as well.

Comment: with the viewJSONService, I thought we needed to create a Web Config/Site document?  If not, I am going to try your answer.  Thank you.  Code should be:  <xe:restService id="rsVictims" pathInfo="rsVictimsData">
  <xe:this.service>
   <xe:viewJsonService categoryFilter="k28ts71zrjsw"
    databaseName="voca\vocadatastore.nsf" defaultColumns="true"
    viewName="InvoiceMPRVictims">
   </xe:viewJsonService>
  </xe:this.service>
 </xe:restService>

Comment: I never created a web config document.  I did have the admin allow the HTTP verbs of PUT and DELETE.  This is done in the address book.    

Also, word to the wise, you should also heed Per Henrik Lausten's suggestion to remove one of your duplicate questions or someone will do it for you.  They run a tight ship here on SO.  

Good luck, getting this right was a struggle for me, so I feel your pain.