# How to add a read/write customRestService to support editing in Dojo DataGrid?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, xpages, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am trying to develop a Dojo DataGrid that returns a user's documents from the categorized BidsByDriver view and allows them to edit the Priority field in the grid. After getting past the hurdle of using the **keys** property to filter over the categoryFilter, this was easy to set up using an xe:viewFileItemService read/write service.  However the problem with  xe:viewFileItemService as a data source is it will display empty lines for each entry in the view after showing the user's documents in the grid.

[image]

To get around the blank lines I went down the path of creating an xe:customRestService that returned the jasonData for just the current user's documents.  This fixes my blank lines problem but my data source is not in the correct read/write format to support the in-grid editing.

Here is the resulting Json data returned form the xe:customRestService ...

```
[{"Driver":"ddd","BidID":"123","Priority":"1","Trip":"644"},
 {"Driver":"ddd","BidID":"123","Priority":"2","Trip":"444"},
 {"Driver":"ddd","BidID":"123","Priority":"4","Trip":"344"},
 {"Driver":"ddd","BidID":"123","Priority":"4","Trip":"643"}
]
```

Here are the Dojo modules I am loading:

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dojo.store.JsonRest"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dojo.data.ObjectStore"></xp:dojoModule>
</xp:this.resources>
```

And here is the script to develop the data store for the grid:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
      <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
    var jsonStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest({target: "InGridCustom.xsp/pathinfo"});  
    var dataStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: jsonStore});
  ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

All of this works very nicely except for the bit on providing the in-grid editing support.  Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Paul, did you enable HTTP PUT for your web site? and does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20383456/785061

Comment: After enabling HTTP PUT, PATCH n DELETE still no difference ... my custonRestService still not supporting in-grid editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you trying to save the changes? With a custom REST service, I would not expect that saving the data store would make any changes to the back-end data, which is why a refresh would revert it to the original value.

I would expect that you'd need to write a doPost method in your custom REST service to process the change on the server side, along with client-side code to call the post method and pass in the updates to process (along with the document ID).

Comment: I suspect you are on the right track but I had to "move off the grid" for this one ... was not worth the pain considering how easy this is to do with dataView control instead.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER:

I would try one or both of these approaches to fix your issue.

1) Have a category in your view, and use a categoryFilter and use the hack to make the service only return the correct values.  Outlines in this question: [XPages Dojo Grid editable cell does not save value when REST Service save() method is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055940/xpages-dojo-grid-editable-cell-does-not-save-value-when-rest-service-save-meth/20383456#20383456)

2) Change the rest service type to viewJsonService in combination with #1.  If you get an error, double check the configuration document that Per mentioned.  Also heed Per's comments in the linked question relating to configuration and using Firebug to make sure the correct method is used. The update must be a PUT, a POST will not work with the viewJsonService.

---

*Original Answer (for context of comments)*

Paul,

I believe that you need to have a button with code to save the changes back.  Maybe you do, but you don't mention it and it isn't in your screen shots. The step that Per mentioned is very necessary so it is good that you have it taken care of.  The button is necessary, to 'commit' the changes back.  The act of inline editing doesn't trigger the PUT call.  If you think about it, you wouldn't want an update after each change but one update when the user is finished editing.

If you don't figure out by this evening, I have working code that I can send you, but don't have access to at work.

Comment: I did not show the code but I do have a button to save the changes in the rest service and refresh the grid.  My problem is that after changing the Priority field in one row, and then moving on the next row, the change I made in the previous row is lost and returned to its original value.  This I believe is because the data source produced by my customRestService is not in the correct format to support write operations.

Comment: Did you try the viewJSONService instead of using either the viewItemFileService or your customRestService?  I eventually got it to work. Also maybe try reaching out to Brad B, who for a while was Mr. DojoGrid. I haven't seen him on SO for a while.

Comment: Yes tried that.  The viewJsonService will also return the blank lines like the image shown above, and it produces an error when used with in-grid editing enabled.

Comment: I remember similar struggles, it was several days of banging my head against my desk before I got it.  I will dig into my code tonight and see if I can find the solution. If I can, I will update the question. I also will shoot you all the code in an email. I assume I can find it on the TLCC site, or I will send you a PM on twitter.